# How to split a string by using more than one delimiter

Tags: vb.net

Below a script I used in my SSIS package.

```
If (Row.AnswerType.Trim().ToUpper = "MULTIPLE SELECT" And _
    Row.SurveyQuestionID = Row.SurveyDefinitionDetailQuestionNumber) Then

    Dim Question1 As String = Row.SurveyDefinitionDetailAnswerChoices.ToUpper.Trim()
    Dim ans1 As String = Row.SurveyAnswer.ToUpper.Trim()

    For Each x As String In ans1.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbTab)})
        If Question1.Contains(x) Then
            Row.IsSkipped = False
        Else
            Row.IsSkipped = True
            'Row.IsAllowed = True
            Row.ErrorDesc = "Invalid Value in Answer Column For Multiple Select!"
        End If
    Next
End If
```

This script only succeeds when having a tab as delimiter. But I need both tab and non tab characters as delimiters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add all the needed characters to the character array

```
ans1.Split(New [Char]() { CChar(vbTab), CChar(" "), CChar(";") })
```

Or

```
ans1.Split(New [Char]() { CChar(vbTab), " "C, ";"C })
```

by using the character literal suffix `C`.